# Javascript from Buffer to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, buffer

I'm using bleno (A node js BLE package) and it uses Buffer to send and receive data. How will I go about getting a Buffer object and converting it into JSON? This is what i have now:

```
bufferToJson = buffer.toString();
bufferToJson = JSON.stringify(bufferToJson)
bufferToJson = JSON.parse(bufferToJson)
```

buffer is where the data is. An example of what buffer can be is `{cmd:'echo'}` I have tried `bufferToJson.cmd` and only get undefine. Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `buffer.toString()` - is it what you expect?

Comment: JSON cannot encode binary data.  You should parse your buffer (probably as UTF8), or use base64.

Comment: {cmd:'echo'} is not valid json. cmd  and echo need double quotes. You could use eval.

Comment: You need to find out the exact format of buffer. You may then use the FileReader API to transform it into a JSON parse-able string

Answer (score 14):

If your *buffer* object contains a valid representation of a JSON, then the easiest way to convert it would be like so:

```
const json = JSON.parse(buffer);
```

Comment: Add `JSON.stringify()` to write the json to a file, ie: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(buffer), null, 2)`.

Answer (score 8):

Following should work:

```
var bufferToJson = JSON.parse(myBuffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) as in following fragment:

```
const buffer = await characteristic.readValue();
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
const text = decoder.decode(buffer);
console.log(JSON.parse(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

For nodejs apps, I found String Decoder to work out great.

https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html

```
// API for decoding Buffer objects into strings
const { StringDecoder } = require('string_decoder');
const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

let body = Buffer.from(response.body);
let json = decoder.write(body);
let foo  = JSON.parse(json);
```