# How to save API request response in Postman to a JSON file when running a collection

Tags: json, postman

I have set up a collection that executes an API request which its payload is a JSON file.

I would like to run this postman collection for several times using different values for a variable that I have set in my request. However, I don't know how to save the API response from my Get request into a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar procedure as well for the automation test. Here were some steps I took:

1. Write a script to execute the postman collection test through postman command line interface modules (https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman), where you can store all the command into a string array with different environment variables you want to specify.

   [new man collection -e env_var.json --reporters cli,json --reporter-json-export output.json, new man second run, ... ]
2. For each execution, you can get the response body by nodejs module and dump the result to json format. (similar to: [output responseBody somewhere with newman script from postman collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555689/output-responsebody-somewhere-with-newman-script-from-postman-collection))
3. Or you can generate the JSON from newman reporter, and parse the JSON to get the informantion you want.

Hope it helps!